# How can one find this limit without L' Hopital's rule?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How can one find this limit
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^{\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x^x}}
$$
without L' Hopital's rule?

Comment: It should be $x\to 0^+$.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this answer will be appropriate, ignoring what you are allowed to use. So, forgive me if my solution is out of the scope.

If you use Taylor series built at $x=0$ and limit to the very first terms, the numerator write
$$\frac{1}{2} x \log ^2(x)+\sqrt{x} \log (x)+1$$
and the denominator write
$$\frac{1}{2} x \log (x)+1$$

If you remember how behaves the product of $\log(x)$ by a positive power of $x$, then you see that the limit is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\ln$ of the function and calculate that limit as $x\to 0$, then exponentiate that limit to get back your original limit. You can do this since $\ln x$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how

> $$ \frac{x^{\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x^x}} = e^{({\sqrt{x}-\frac{x}{2}}) \ln(x)} \longrightarrow_{x\to 0} 1 .$$